# Pass the array values from javascript code to php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I'm trying to pass the values of array to php but i can not get the values. It returns NULL, when I use var_dump() it returns array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } Array ( [0] => )

Here the code:

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
   var newhour= [];
   for (var i = 0; i < arrayNumbers.length; i++) {
        newhour.push(arrayNumbers[i].toString().split(','));   
        console.log("each: " + newhour[i]); // output: each: 07:00,08:30
                                                       each: 18:00,19:00                                                   
   }
   console.log("all: " + newhour); //output: all: 07:00,08:30,18:00,19:00

   var jsonx = JSON.stringify(newhour);
   console.log("x: " +jsonx); // output: x: [["07:00","08:30"],["18:00","19:00"]]
   $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "hour.php",
         data:{data: jsonx}, 
         cache: false,
         success: function(){
                  alert("OK");
         }
   });
});
```

hour.php file include:

```
  $data = json_decode($_POST['data'],true);
//$data = json_decode(($_POST['data']));  
//$data = explode(",", $_POST['data']);
//$data = $_POST['data']; 
  echo "data: " .$data;
  var_dump($data);
  foreach($data as $d){
        echo $d;
  }
```

I struggled with that for hours, i tried everything but couldn't get any values.
I don not understand where I'm wrong.
Can you please help me with my code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you just use print_r($_POST['data']); and paste output here?

Comment: @SachinVairagi It does not return any thing. I do not why.

Comment: Look at your browser's debugger tool's network inspector and see what the exact raw HTTP request is, for starters.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me
This is the data I used for arrayNumbers

`var arrayNumbers = [1, 591, 283, 12];`

This is the return data

`data: Arrayarray(4) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } 
    [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "591" } 
    [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "283" } 
    [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "12" } 
} ArrayArrayArrayArray`

**EDIT**: just tried a few different values for arrayNumbers. When i used `var arrayNumbers = [""];` I got your exact return. Check what values you are using for that because thats the issue.

Note: I also had to comment out `each: 18:00,19:00`, but I assumed you already had that commented and copied it wrong